# How to move my Joomla website from localhost and host it on GoDaddy

Tags: php, joomla, web-hosting

I am new to Joomla and Hosting,

i have downloaded a Joomla template from a website. the package contains the hole template including the database and all the structure(html, css) and all the web parts. i did my changes locally and want to move the website and host it on GoDaddy. But first i need to buy a hosting and move the files to the server.

now GoDaddy have a ready Joomla installation plus hosting, if i purchase that and take the template and install it, i would loose the the added html and content provided.

what is the best practices to to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore GoDaddy's Joomla installation, you don't need it. Just upload your files, export/import your database, and update your `configuration.php` file with the new paths & connection information.

Comment: Thank you Martin, so i copy the files i have under IIS(all of them) then i export my database (mysql) using workbench, to .sql then i import it (i would appreciate if you can provide me with a link that explains how to export and import a database to a joomla website), and when changing the configuration files from where do i need to retrieve the paths and connection strings. another thing is do i need to buy a specific hosting on GoDaddy for the database? forgive me but i am really new to this world of technology.

Comment: @JohnnyZghaib I don't use workbench, but GoDaddy should provide something similar such as phpMyAdmin. You can find the path information either by asking hosting support, or by creating a file that contains the following code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. The connection info should all be in your control panel.